# encrypt- decrypt with SHA256 using java

Tags: security, cryptography, hash

Please help me the code (Java) to encrypt and decrypt ( will be better if using private key) with SHA256.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're confused about what SHA is. SHA is a [Cryptographic Hash Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), not an encryption algorithm. You can't reverse the operation to determine the message that was used to generate a particular hash.

Answer (score 11):

The **S***ecure* **H***ash* **A***lgorithm* family of functions are *one-way* functions. You can use the functions to get a cryptographic hash from any given input, but it is impossible to reverse the function and arrive at the input from any given output hash.

Answer (score 6):

There have actually been several techniques proposed for turning hash functions into block ciphers that can encrypt and decrypt - for example Peter Gutmann's "Message Digest Cipher".

[This paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/xu0qg98tg38gl7nf/) has some cryptanalysis of some of these techniques.

But you *really* don't want to do this - you are far better off using a well-studied block cipher, like AES.

Answer (score 4):

SHA-256 is a one way algorithm, it cannot be decrypted!

Comment: How to this website work ?. https://md5decrypt.net/en/Sha256/#answer