# How to convert hash data to original data?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, cryptography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to decrypt md5 hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-md5-hashes)

I hashed data with `ComputeHash` how can I learn original data from hashed data?

```
private void btn_Hash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HashAlgorithm ha = HashAlgorithm.Create();
    Stream file = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\simetrik.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    hashClass.hash = ha.ComputeHash(file);

    listBox1.Items.Add(BitConverter.ToString(hashClass.hash));
}
```

Comment: when you say 'learn original data' do you mean recover from hash, or identify the file that the hash came from?

Comment: Try searching first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760911 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153257 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240852 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471654 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717950 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235079 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153694 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161157 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298018 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501230

Comment: But wait:  there's more!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006710 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298018 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625542 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562064 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173329 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600326 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486887 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653900 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263766 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524182

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't.  The whole point of a [cryptographic hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is that it's supposed to be computationally infeasible to reverse in general.  The best you can do is check known dictionaries and [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).  Neither of these will help much for unique plaintext.  Perhaps you should be using an [encryption algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) instead.

Also, you should explicitly specify the algorithm you want.  E.g.:

```
HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert it back, hashing works only one way. The reason is that (1) it looses data - your hash uses much less memory than the original data. Think about string being hashed to int (2) many hashing algorithms are deliberately constructed in a way to make it computationally impossible to reverse them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use a [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table), but I'm sure this is not exactly what you want. :)

Comment: A rainbow table is not a magical method that can find the preimage of the hash of arbitrary amounts of data.